# DataStax Cassandra java driver crashes with NoHostAvailableException after a few hundred inserts

Tags: java, cassandra

I want to write an application that writes 5 Strings (related to file assets) to Cassandra.  I based the code off the tutorials in DataStax's documentation.  It works for about 30 seconds for a few hundred inserts, but crashes with the error:

```
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (no host was tried)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException.copy(NoHostAvailableException.java:65)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.extractCauseFromExecutionException(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:256)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.getUninterruptibly(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:172)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.execute(AbstractSession.java:52)
...
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (no host was tried)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.sendRequest(RequestHandler.java:103)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager.execute(SessionManager.java:368)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager.executeQuery(SessionManager.java:404)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager.executeAsync(SessionManager.java:85)
    ... 8 more
```

The process is still running and I can re-run the unit test with the same results: a few hundred inserts and then this error.  The server shows no sign of distress or error.

I am using the driver:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Here's my client code:

```java
private static final String BOUND_STATEMENT = "INSERT INTO myschema.files(file_name, md5, last_modified, size, hash_date) "
        + "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";
@Override
public void persist(FileEntry entry) {
    Session session = cluster.connect();
    //prepare statement, if it doesn't exist.
    if (persistPs == null) {
        persistPs = session.prepare(BOUND_STATEMENT);
    }
    BoundStatement boundStatement = new BoundStatement(persistPs);
    session.execute(boundStatement.bind(entry.getFileName(), entry.getMd5(), entry.getLastModified(),
            entry.getSize(), entry.getHashDate()));
    session.close();
    System.out.print(".");
}
```

I am running Cassandra 2.0.9 on my localhost (OSX with a solid state drive and recent macbook).

Any leads on how to make this not crash?  If this is just an issue with the DataStax driver, I'd be happy to use any other driver.

I'm not generating too severe of a load and the server process is not throwing any exceptions or hints as to what can be going wrong.  I have heard of other organizations having success with Cassandra, so I assume it's with my client code.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked that the Cassandra server processes are running?

Comment: Thank you for responding Raedwald.  It is running.  I updated the question to make it more clear that there's no sign of issue with the server.  It appears to be my client code.

Comment: Is the `system.log` on your server logging an error at that time?

Comment: Also, there's no need to keep opening and closing your session.  Try rewriting your `persist` method to accept the `session` as a parameter.  Then call connect once at the beginning of your `main` and close at the end.

Comment: Steve I am facing similar problem here. Updated the driver from 2.0.3 to 2.0.4 but same issue. I have a 5 nodes dev-cluster and when I leave the cluster idle for a while (no rw op) I can not connect anymore. After restart of application (without touching any of the nodes) things start working again. Watching the getErrors() it say Read time out from EACH of the five nodes. I have red about similar problem in 2.0.7 fixed in 2.0.8 -- I though an update could fix but  you have problem in 2.0.9 -- if we don't find solution I open an issue in the datastax java driver jira queue.

Comment: Thank you Bryce, keeping the session open made it last much longer, but now instead of running for 30 seconds or so, it runs for 2 or 3 minutes.

Answer (score 3):

BryceAtNetwork23 was correct.  The issue was "solved" by my passing the session object from call to call.

```
public final void persist(final FileEntry entry, final Session session) {
    prepareInsertStatement(session);
    final BoundStatement boundStatement = new BoundStatement(persistPs);
    //bind values from our bean to our insert query
    session.execute(boundStatement.bind(entry.getFileName(), entry.getMd5(), entry.getLastModified(),
            entry.getSize(), entry.getHashDate()));
}

private final synchronized void prepareInsertStatement(final Session session) {
    // prepare statement, if it doesn't exist.
    if (persistPs == null) {
        persistPs = session.prepare(BOUND_STATEMENT);
    }
}
```

I don't know if this is an issue with the scalability of Cassandra's engine or DataStax's driver, but normally, I have to work a LOT harder than one day with a platform to bring it to it's knees.  Regardless, I am frustrated at their documentation.  I have never had this much trouble with a platform getting it to run without crashing.  Their examples crash a single node after something like 1000 inserts.  If we're evaluating Cassandra, chances are we want to insert a lot more than 1000 rows.

That said, once I passed the session from call to call, the code ran pretty quickly and performs nicely.  I have some ambivalence, but am happy everything finally works.  Thanks for your help everybody.